# How to show only last marker on multiple exact location on google maps with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add only last marker if the location has multiple exact longitude and latitude.

This is my controller:

```
.controller('MapsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

 var map;

 //Marker clusterer
 var mc;
 var mcOptions = { gridSize: 20, maxZoom: 17, imagePath: "images/m" };

 //Global infoWindow
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 //Geocoder
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 $scope.loadData = function () {
     var url = 'data/LatLng.json';
     return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
         return response.data;
     });
 };

 function createMarker(latlng, info, data) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latlng,
         map: map
     });

     //Get array of markers currently in cluster
     var allMarkers = mc.getMarkers();

     //Check to see if any of the existing markers match the latlng of the new marker
     if (allMarkers.length != 0) {

         var count = 1;
         var morethanone = false;

         for (var i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {

             var existingMarker = allMarkers[i];
             var pos = existingMarker.getPosition();

             if (latlng.equals(pos)) {

                 info = info + info;

                 count = count + 1;
                 morethanone = true;
             }
         }
     }

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
         infowindow.close();
         infowindow.setContent(info);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     });

     if (morethanone) {
         for (var a = 1; a < count; a++) {
             if (a === (count - 1)) {
                 marker.setLabel(String(count));
                 mc.addMarker(marker);
             }
         }
     }
     else {
         marker.setLabel(String(count));
         mc.addMarker(marker);
     }
     console.log(count);
     return marker;
 }

 $scope.initMap = function (data) {
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 7,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.9443, 101.6954),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

     var gmarkers = [];
     mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

     data.forEach(function (item) {

         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.LAT, item.LON);
         var info = item.Cat + "," + item.Type;
         gmarkers.push(createMarker(latlng, info, data));
     });
 };

 $scope.loadData()
     .then($scope.initMap);

 }])
```

However the code will add more than one marker on the same location, so in this case I have five exactly same location and the marker overlapped five times each other, which is not nice. You can refer to the image below:

[image]

What I want is only show one marker (which is the last marker) with label '5' on it.

Any ideas how to do it?

Thank You.

Comment: I think your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.  When there is more than one marker you are still adding it the marker cluster.  Additionally, because when you create the marker you are passing in 'map' in the configuration, that marker will be attached to that map.  You need to do a check before you create the new marker, or avoid assigning the marker to a map until after you have checked.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this.

```
.controller('MapsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

 var map;    
 //Marker clusterer
 var mc;
 var mcOptions = { gridSize: 20, maxZoom: 17, imagePath: "images/m" };

 //Global infoWindow
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 //Geocoder
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 $scope.loadData = function () {
     var url = 'data/LatLng.json';
     return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
         return response.data;
     });
 };

    $scope.initMap = function (data) {
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 7,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.9443, 101.6954),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

     var gmarkers = [];
     mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

     data.forEach(function (item) {    
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.LAT, item.LON);
         var info = item.Cat + "," + item.Type;
         gmarkers.push(createMarker(latlng, info, data));
     });
 };


 function createMarker(latlng, info, data) {
    //Get array of markers currently in cluster
    var allMarkers = mc.getMarkers();

    // Filter to duplicate markers
    var dupeMarkers = allMarkers.filter(function (existingMarker) {
         var pos = existingMarker.getPostion();
         return latlng.equals(pos)
     });

    // Remove duplicate markers
     dupeMarkers.forEach(function(dupeMarker) {
         mc.removeMarker(dupeMarker);  // remove from cluster
         dupeMarker.setMap(null);  // remove from map
     });

     // Add marker to the map
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latlng,
         map: map
     });            

     // Add marker to the cluster
     mc.addMarker(newMarker);

     // If you want to set the label to count of markers that are / were at this location
     marker.setLabel(dupeMarkers.length + 1);

     google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'click', function () {
         infowindow.close();
         infowindow.setContent(info);
         infowindow.open(map, newMarker);
     });

     return newMarker;
 }


 $scope.loadData()
     .then($scope.initMap);    
 }]);
```

Comment: The flaw in this is that since the code is removing the dupe markers that it won't know that markers were there before.  You can modify the code to keep track of the count and increment it.

Comment: Hi @Ray, could you show me where should I put the counter?

Comment: Hi @Ray, I have tried your code, it is not working. It still adding multiple label on it like my previous code.

Comment: @CoolTips2u did you get this working?  I'd be happy to take a look if you post the code up in a js fiddle or something.

Comment: Hi @Ray Suelzer, I didn't manage to make it works. I decided to remove the number label from the marker. Thanks.